# Merge sms, messaging and text-message

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

Noticed that we've got a few tags related to SMS that ought to be merged (I think under SMS because that's the most precise term)

[sms](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sms) [messaging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/messaging) [text-message](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-message)

Comment: Related note: I think `instant-message` should be renamed to `instant-messaging`.

Comment: Done. There were just two.

Comment: you can use tag syntax in situations like this: `[tag:sms] [tag:messaging]` etc

Answer (score 3):

Sounds good to me, especially since it appears users aren't using [messaging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/messaging) to refer to email or anything else but SMS.

I have proposed the other two as synonyms for [sms](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sms) ([link](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/sms/synonyms)).

On the other hand, [instant-message](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instant-message) is proposed as a synonym for [messaging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/messaging), which I disagree with since again, users have only used [messaging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/messaging) for SMS.

Comment: Instant message more accurately refers to IM clients, like AIM and Google Talk. "Messaging" could refer to IM and/or SMS.

Comment: Agreed. It looked like all the "messaging" questions were SMS related. The two instant-messaging questions are about AIM/Jabber clients.

Comment: Since "messaging" could count for either or both, it probably should go away. Trouble is people will probably still use it, so it needs to be a synonym or have a rock-solid definition.